# How to make SoapClient request with complex parameters?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

This is the first time I work with SoapClient on PHP. My task is to create a script to automatically send a Soap request to the server. The correct request in SOAP UI is:

Soap URL: http://example.com:8181/inventory/soap/inventory-api?wsdl

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inv="http://example.com:8181/inventory-api/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <inv:searchStockItemRequest>
         <inv:filter>
            <inv:ItemID>100</inv:ItemID>
            <inv:ItemID>101</inv:ItemID>
            <inv:ItemID>102</inv:ItemID>
         </inv:filter>
      </inv:searchStockItemRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It means: Search the StockItem with ID is 100 or 101 or 102.
This is my current code.

```
$xml = '<inv:filter>
            <inv:ItemID>100</inv:ItemID>
            <inv:ItemID>101</inv:ItemID>
            <inv:ItemID>102</inv:ItemID>
         </inv:filter>';
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => 'http://example.com:8181/inventory/soap/inventory-api?wsdl',
    'uri' => MCA_INVENTORY_WSDL)
);
$result = $client->searchItem(htmlspecialchars($xml));
```

And the result is fault with a message:

"Missing required element {http://example.com:8181/inventory-api/}filter"

I think that the server cannot detect the above filter element. Anyone please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Soap URL: http://example.com:8181/inventory/soap/inventory-api?wsdl
```

This is your wsdl address, not your service end point url.

Open above url in web browser. Find this tag `<soap:address location>` in your wsdl. It should be within `<service>` tag at end of wsdl. Now replace wsdl url with this end point url.
It should work.

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => 'http://example.com:8181/inventory/soap/inventory-api?wsdl',
'uri' => MCA_INVENTORY_WSDL)
```

Comment: This is what I've got when opening it on browser:

_<error><description>Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service</description><reason>If you wish Axis2 to automatically generate the WSDL 1.1, then please set useOriginalwsdl as false in your services.xml</reason></error>_

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a correct data format instead of a XML string. Based on your correct request using SOAP UI, the code using SoapClient should be like the below:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://example.com:8181/inventory/soap/inventory-api?wsdl');
$result = $client->searchStockItemRequest(array(
    'filter' => array(
        'ItemID' => array(100, 101, 102)
    )
));
```

I am not sure the `ItemID` array is a correct format. You can print the request to check:

```
echo $client->__getLastRequest();
```

Don't forget to enable the tracing option:

```
 $client = new SoapClient('...', array('trace' => true));
```